# Sharepoint busy and preventing Access writes

Tags: microsoft-access, time-out

I am from an Access VBA background and unfamiliar with SharePoint.
I have a query which writes to a SharePoint List, which was set up in Access using the wizards in Access 2010. The wizard creates a table like object and I have used conventional/simple VBA SQL to query it.
My problem is that the SP list has workflows attached to some of the fields that I am updating. If these workflows are triggered, then Access sometimes reports an error and times out. In the Access debugger, simply waiting for a minute or two and then pressing F5 to continue, resumes processing without error, so my code seems to function correctly.
What is the correct mechanism for checking that SharePoint is 'ready' for an update?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by replicating a human - I detect the error and then wait a minute before resuming - bingo!
Crude, but it works. I'm sure that there must be a 'proper' way...
John